# blocked processes in a 5 state process model

Tags: multithreading

I am coding a 5 state process model(new,ready,running,blocked,exit), for this I created a LinkedList which contains the processes ready to run. For example if I have the processes 1,2,3,4,5 it runs the 1st, then the 2nd, and when the third is running the user pushes a button and blocks the process for 5 seconds. In the meantime the following process(the 4th) runs(it doesn´t wait until the third process is unblocked). The problem that I have is that I don´t know if I should use two threads for this, one for the threads that are running and the other for the blocked process?? or is it possible to only use one thread???

Answer (score 0):

You could use only a single thread if you use cooperative multitasking, where your process code periodically yields to permit other processes to run, or if you want each task to run to completion or blocking before letting another process in or back in.

If it's important that the 3rd process restart after exactly 5 seconds, and if it's okay for it to continue running in parallel with an existing process also running, you might want to use two - or more - threads.